# Changing Floating Filter Style in Ag-Grid for Angular

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid for the first time. I've implemented a floating filter, but the default style clashes with the look of the rest of my grid, so I'd like to change it. Ideally I'd like to change the class itself, but I'd settle for just being able to change the background color and width. However nothing I try works, and the examples I can find don't work for me at all. This is an example of one of my column definitions:

```
{field: 'quantity', headerName: 'Quantity', filter:'agTextColumnFilter', floatingFilterComponentParams: {suppressFilterButton:true, cellStyle: {'background-color':'blue'}}},
```

My app compiles just fine, but the cellStyle change I make doesn't reflect in the app at all. Does anyone know what I'm missing here?